# How to pass data from popup window to parent window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

Basically I want to create something like this [skyweaver](https://www.skyweaver.net/) when clicking login it opens [sequence app](https://sequence.app/) auth flow completes, then in skyweaver we are logged in,  How do I mimic that feature.

I'm not sure this was implemented using iframe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't an iframe, but a popup window with its controls hidden. Those are spawned via [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Underneath the hood, the JS loaded inside this window will be using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to inform the parent window of certain events -- like passing auth tokens around.

In react, things get a bit easier since you can use [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to load a React component in your parent app into the popup window. If you google around "react portal popup window" you'll get a lot of guidance on how to do this.

Typically, you wouldn't implement all this yourself as Auth is well-trodden ground with many open source libraries to lean on. The most popular is [auth0](https://auth0.com/). But it depends on your requirements, for example, if you need the social login or you are just logging into an existing auth system. If the latter you could layer on the `window.open` and `window.postMessage` stuff on top of what you already have.